Full-text search and order by
I have around 16kk rows in the Postgres table and want to use full-text search there, chose to use GIN index for this - already created and works
This query performs for up to 300ms:
SELECT * FROM products WHERE to_tsvector('english', iid) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'dsdsdsd') LIMIT 1000
But when I add sorting, perform time increases many times (up to 1min):
SELECT * FROM products WHERE to_tsvector('english', iid) @@ plainto_tsquery('english', 'dsdsdsd') ORDER BY updated_utc DESC LIMIT 1000
Same time updated_utc column has a b-tree index, that works on queries w/o full-text search
I need to find 1k of newest coincidences
I tried:

btree_gin extension to create complicated index (iid and updated_utc both)
CTE expression - no enhancements
Subqueries: with IN syntax - too slow, with SELECT FROM SELECT - don't work. I need to find 1k of newest coincidences, so can't use LIMIT inside subquery
work_mem increased to 5gb - this helped with some queries, but not with example

Is there any way to do sort fast on current schema or I need to create separate table for vectors (which is definitely the way, but there are some architecture restrictions, so use this is undesirable)? It's important to note, that queries with searching text that actually exists in table perform very quickly and use gin index as well.
First query EXPLAIN:
Limit  (cost=522.14..3731.03 rows=1000 width=2270) (actual time=0.012..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3
  ->  Bitmap Heap Scan on public.products  (cost=522.14..241143.54 rows=74986 width=2270) (actual time=0.011..0.012 rows=0 loops=1)
        Recheck Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (products.iid)::text) @@ '''dsdsdsd'''::tsquery)
        Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3
        ->  Bitmap Index Scan on iid_gin_idx  (cost=0.00..503.39 rows=74986 width=0) (actual time=0.010..0.010 rows=0 loops=1)
              Index Cond: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (products.iid)::text) @@ '''dsdsdsd'''::tsquery)
              Buffers: shared hit=1 read=3
Settings: work_mem = '5GB'
Planning:
  Buffers: shared read=1
Planning Time: 0.120 ms
Execution Time: 0.030 ms

Second query EXPLAIN:
Limit  (cost=1000.46..45563.27 rows=1000 width=2270) (actual time=46126.760..46129.022 rows=0 loops=1)
  Buffers: shared hit=119071 read=1037447
  ->  Gather Merge  (cost=1000.46..3342587.06 rows=74986 width=2270) (actual time=46126.759..46129.020 rows=0 loops=1)
        Workers Planned: 2
        Workers Launched: 2
        Buffers: shared hit=119071 read=1037447
        ->  Parallel Index Scan Backward using products_updated_utc_idx on public.products  (cost=0.43..3332931.79 rows=31244 width=2270) (actual time=46120.229..46120.230 rows=0 loops=3)
              Filter: (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, (products.iid)::text) @@ '''dsdsdsd'''::tsquery)
              Rows Removed by Filter: 4999090
              Buffers: shared hit=119071 read=1037447
              Worker 0:  actual time=46123.871..46123.871 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=40133 read=348446
              Worker 1:  actual time=46118.681..46118.681 rows=0 loops=1
                Buffers: shared hit=39632 read=345921
Settings: work_mem = '5GB'
Planning:
  Buffers: shared read=1
Planning Time: 0.104 ms
Execution Time: 46129.043 ms

Table DDL:
create table if not exists public.products
(
    iid                       varchar(256)             not null,
    value                     numeric(9, 4)            not null,
    param                     integer,
    param_str                 varchar(256),
    created                   timestamp with time zone not null,
    updated                   timestamp with time zone,
    removed                   timestamp with time zone,
    blocked                   boolean                  not null,
    provider_iid              smallint,
    team_raw_name             varchar(256),
    market_iid                smallint,
    submarket_iid             smallint,
    category_iid              smallint,
    fetch_ts                  numeric(16, 6),
    updated_utc               timestamp with time zone not null,
    is_primary                boolean default false    not null,
);

Indexes DDLs:
create index if not exists iid_gin_idx
    on public.products using gin (to_tsvector('english'::regconfig, iid::text));

create index if not exists products_updated_utc_idx
    on public.products (updated_utc);


Have you VACUUM (ANALYZE)-ed the table recently? The query planner estimates to the number of rows returned seems way off. It thinks it might get ~75k rows, when actually it gets zero.

This answer might be useful: https://stackoverflow.com/a/77828916/529630 In brief, you tell postgres to increase the number of words it keeps statistics on. The question appears much the same as yours -- searching for a rare or non-existent word.

It looks to me like you have not run ANALYZE on the table since you added the index.  Functional indexes get their own stats, but they need to be populated.

@Dunes thanks for help guys, forgot for this, finally it worked
